# CSS: round buttons with shadow effect

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate the navigation buttons [here](http://wix.com/), that's a wix website so it's so hard to inspect elements.

What I have tried is here

https://jsfiddle.net/1vngy4uo/1/

I'm trying many variations, never getting the css 100% correct.

```
.navButton {
    width:15%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#03314b;
    border-radius: 30%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
}
 .navButton:hover {
    background-color:#98b7c8;
}
.navButton span {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 30%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
}
.navButton .bg {
    height:50%;
    top:0;
    background-color:#3a6076 ;
    border-radius: 30%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
}
.navButton:hover .bg{
    background-color:#afcad9;

}
.navButton .text {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    align-items: center;
}
.navButton .text:hover {
    color:#000000;
}
```

and html

```
<a href="contact.html" class="navButton">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <span class="text">Contact</span>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rum5mtnw/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9L60y8c6/2/

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the site is generated - inspecting an element is the same for any website. You can always expect there to be an HTML element with CSS applied to it. In the site you referenced, they are using a background image and other CSS - and it's fairly easy to see that by inspecting it.

Comment: @RyanWheale yes but the css is a mess and I don't want to use a background image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very similar one, using `linear-gradient` and less HTML markup

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rum5mtnw/2/)

```css
.navButton {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#335b71 45%, #03324c 55%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #888888;
  transition: color 0.3s, background-image 0.5s, ease-in-out;
}
.navButton:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#b1ccda 49%, #96b4c5 51%);
  color: #03324c;
}
```

```html
<a href="contact.html" class="navButton">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, well you're certainly right, but IE9 usage is 0.43% and IE8 is 0.63%, so IE8 scares me more :), also with `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` rule it could be fixed with an image or `:before` and `:after` as pollyfill

Comment: I did the `:before` in my answer ... and the usage percent depends on where you check, as reality is not that bad for IE9, but agree, IE8 has a higher usage, which my answer solve too :)

Comment: also in http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ it uses a fix for CSS gradient , for example `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( )` which works on IE6+ , as well as vendor prefixes, so it could be be used too.

Comment: MS `filter` won't work in IE9 ... a SVG does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38673089/2827823

Comment: Yeah you're right just checked it and it didn't work, will still, the old school `1px` width background image always work :)

Answer (score 2):

Would this be a start? You might want to adjust the colors a little.

*Note: One can use linear-gradient, though it won't work on IE9, so I use a pseudo instead*

```css
.navButton {
  width: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #03314b;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navButton:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #335b71;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.navButton span {
  position: relative;
}
.navButton:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: #96b4c5;
  color: black;
}
.navButton:hover:before {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: #b1ccda;
}
```

```html
<a href="contact.html" class="navButton">
  <span>Contact</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just used a div element to implement the same button that you referred. Is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/9L60y8c6/

```
<div class="test">

</div>

.test {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(4, 53, 81, 1) url(//static.parastorage.com/services/skins/2.1212.0/images/wysiwyg/core/themes/base/shiny1button_bg.png) center center repeat-x;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 115px;
}
```